# Highlight not working with elasticsearch script_score query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get query result along with highlight but highlights are not working script_score query in elasticsearch version 7.13. I am tryig following query

```
{
  "_source": {"excludes": ["tag","document_vector"]},
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'document_vector') + 1.0",
        "params": {
          "query_vector": query_vector
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "highlight": {
    "order": "score",
    "number_of_fragments": 3,
    "fragment_size": 150,
    "pre_tags": [
      "<mark>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</mark>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "content": {}
    }
  }
```

Comment: What it's supposed to highlights since you do not specify any matching sequence, only exclusion.

Comment: I am trying to highlight the content (text content) field, which is one of keys in the results.

Comment: highlights is to find which terms in you query is matching the field and encapsulate it with tags, you do not specify any filtering on the content field so you cannot have any term highlighted

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not getting the highlight key and value in the response at all. Althoght the query is returning documents / respnse for all needed field.